# applay limit after leftJoin typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, nest

is there any way to get limited data after applying joins in Typeorm.

`this.menuRepository.createQueryBuilder('menu') .leftJoinAndSelect('menu.category','category') .leftJoinAndSelect('category.items', 'items') .getMany();`

here is my query. I want to get first 5 "items". I have used .limit(5) but it applied limit on menu, category as well.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the complete query including `limit` clause, the actual results the expected results of that data. All as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful.